# HTML value field to be Javascript item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

This message is being posted on behalf of a friend who is having trouble making an account,

"IT has been a while since I have used HTML and JS, I would like a value field to be populated from a JS item. here is my code below to give context

```
<select size='3' name='selectAlbum' onchange='albumSelect();'>
<option selected='selected' id='album1'>album1</option>
<option id='album2' value=albums[0].title>album2</option>
<option id='album3'>album3</option>
</select>
```

albums[0] = JSON."

Appreciate any help given,
Thanks.

Comment: `$('#album2').val(albums[0].title);`?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more to work with? It depends what is stored in the item and what you want to change e.g. each option or one option?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, [yes it does](http://jsfiddle.net/utk1r9wa/2/)

Comment: @Andy My mistake. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use jQuery. For example:

```
$(function () {
  var albums = [{ title: 'bob' }]; 
  $('#album2').val(albums[0].title);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/utk1r9wa/2/)

Or you can use vanilla JS:

```
var album2 = document.getElementById('album2').value = albums[0].title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$(function () {
  // Dummy code below: Make sure you initialize `albums` correctly.
  albums[0] = JSON;
  $("#album2").val(albums[0].title);
});
```

This is the way you need to set the value.